# How do i get the children of a TemplatedView or other xamarin controls

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Within a TemplatedView you can overload OnChildAdded and other methods.

However there is no property to access the fields.

How does Xamarin want me to access those children?

**To spare people who do not have ReSharper i will post the answer how to get this done without a fugly solution (like storing references and potentially causing leaks)**

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class LayoutControllerExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Element> GetChildren(this ILayoutController source)
    {
        return source.Children;
    }
}
```

That's probably the cleanest approach until MS overhauls the API.